# VBA function works only in one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write functions to automate some of my routine calculations. 
 However there are the following problems I came across:

1. `SumbyCode1` function always works in the sheet that contains the data. However, it doesn't work in other worksheets of the same workbook.
2. `CountbyCode` function doesn't work. I tried the function as an ordinary sub, and it works perfectly there. However, then I apply the codes in function. It doesn't work at all.

See codes below:

```
Public Function SumbyCode1(ByRef wirecode0, Optional ByRef wirecode1, _
                           Optional ByRef wirecode2, Optional ByRef wirecode3, _
                           Optional ByRef wirecode4, Optional ByRef wirecode5, _
                           Optional ByRef wirecode6, Optional ByRef wirecode7, _
                           Optional ByRef wirecode8)
    Dim var()
    var = Array(wirecode0, wirecode1, wirecode2, wirecode3, wirecode4, _
                wirecode5, wirecode6, wirecode7, wirecode8)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Banking Transaction")
    Dim colnumbercode As Integer
    Dim colnumberamount As Integer
    Dim total As Variant
    total = 0

    With ws
        colnumbercode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Type", Range("1:1"), 0)
        colnumbercodeletter = Chr(64 + colnumbercode)
        codecol = colnumbercodeletter & ":" & colnumbercodeletter
        colnumberamount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Amount", Range("1:1"), 0)
        colnumberamountletter = Chr(64 + colnumberamount)
        codeamount = colnumberamountletter & ":" & colnumberamountletter

        For i = 0 To 8
            total = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(codecol), _
            var(i), Range(codeamount)) + total
        Next i
    End With
    SumbyCode1 = total

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function CountbyCode(ByRef wirecode0, Optional ByRef wirecode1, _
                            Optional ByRef wirecode2, Optional ByRef wirecode3, _
                            Optional ByRef wirecode4, Optional ByRef wirecode5, _
                            Optional ByRef wirecode6, Optional ByRef wirecode7, _
                            Optional ByRef wirecode8)
    Dim var()
    var = Array(wirecode0, wirecode1, wirecode2, wirecode3, _
                wirecode4, wirecode5, wirecode6, wirecode7, wirecode8)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Banking Transaction")
    Dim colnumbercode As Integer
    Dim total As Variant
    total = 0

    With ws
        colnumbercode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Type", Range("1:1"), 0)
        colnumbercodeletter = Chr(64 + colnumbercode)
        codecol = colnumbercodeletter & ":" & colnumbercodeletter

        For i = 0 To 8
        total = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(codecol), _
                var(i)) + total
        Next i
    End With
    CountbyCode = total

End Function
```

Comment: when using `With ws` all range object that should be assigned to this sheet need to have `.` in front of it.  For example: `colnumbercode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Type", .Range("1:1"), 0)`

Comment: Please consider using the line continuation `_` when posting long lines, to save us (and you) from all that horizontal scrolling...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and suggestion. It works now!

Answer (score 2):

You need to fully qualify your references. When you use:

`total = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(codecol), var(i)) + total`

The VB Editor silently interprets `Range(codecol)` as `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(codecol)`, which means the function only works on the currently active sheet. As @ScottCraner suggested, you need to change that to a fully explicit reference using your previous `With ws` declaration by changing `Range(codecol)` to `.Range(codecol)`.

Comment: As a user of the Rubberduck VBE add-in, you may appreciate knowing that Rubberduck's code inspections could catch and automatically fix this error (and many others like it) for you in the future. http://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. I'll read the reference you mentioned for further improvement. Thanks again!